# Reading Configuration in Play (2.6.5) with Scala without @Inject

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play 2.6.5 with Scala. Most of the times reading from the configuration works with injecting the configuration.

In some parts it would be too difficult to get a class into injection scope.

Is there a way to get the configuration object without injection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ConfigFactory ->

```
ConfigFactory.load().getString("db.url")
```

import for the same ->

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
```

Comment: Works! You are my hero, sir.

Comment: How to get an `Option` instead of `null`s?